# Is there a simple way to allow tabbing between non-VCL and VCL controls on a Delphi form?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, tab-ordering

I have a Delphi form with a bunch of VCL controls, like TButton and TCheckBox, and an instance of the [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) text editor.  I want to be able to tab into and out of the text editor but it looks like tabs are handled by the VCL library not Windows.

I stepped though the code and it looks like tabs are handled by the SelectNext and FindNextControl methods of the TWinControl class.  These methods work on TWinControl objects but the text editor does not descend from TWinControl like TButton and TCheckbox.

Is there a simple way to allow tabbing between non-VCL and VCL controls?

Comment: What wrapper for the Scintilla library do you use?

Comment: I don't use a wrapper.  CreateWindowEx to create it and SendMessage to communicate with it.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to make your own wrapper class for it. It doesn't have to expose any properties or methods. Use TStaticText or TEdit as an example of how to make a TWinControl descendant call CreateWindowEx with the right window class name. You get a bunch of stuff free that way, such as alignment, sizing, and tabbing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(made this a wiki answer, because Rob is quite correct in his comments above, this just regurgitates it)

Keyboard handling for special characters / keys  is handled in a fairly special way by the VCL, and bypassing / extending this directly via the Win API is certainly do-able but non-trivial.

It would be just as easy and frankly more flexible in the long run if you create a Custom VCL component wrapper around the controls (use the VCL source as a guide) it's really not all that hard (maybe a little tedious) but the pay-off will be tremendous in terms of maintainability and re-use.

Edit:

And of course you could simply use this [free Delphi Wrapper](http://delphisci.sourceforge.net/) for the Scintilla editor.